# How do I change priority in debian?

Tags: linux, process, debian, taskmanager, raspbian

I am using Raspbian, a Debian distro for the Raspberry Pi. I tried using the task manager but was unable to change the process priority (I was trying to decrease Python's priority). After decreasing the priority and checking again it remained at zero (no change). Is this because of me not being a superuser? If so how do I open the task manager GUI in sudo? If not what else could be the problem?

Comment: which command did you use for decreasing priority?
And obviously you need sudo rights, if you are not the admin

Comment: I used a GUI interface that was provided with it. I did not use any commands. Is there a way to open GUI applications as sudo, I don't want to login with full root access?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider to use Terminal:

```
sudo top
```

this will show you the processes with pid

```
renice {priority} pid
```

this will change the priority (niceness) of the process. The nicer the process is, the lower priority it will have. It's nicer because leave its time-slot to other processes ;-)

{priority} is from -20 to 19

Answer (score 3):

Find the process id (using ps aux|grep 'your_process')

Use `renice` command

```
$sudo renice -n <nice_value> -p <PID>
```

Comment: I will try. thanks a lot. -n and -p are the amount of priority decrease and process id, aren't they?

Comment: -p is the process's ID and n is the actual priority (nice value) between -20 & 20. More negative means higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

xrenice, like xkill lets you to renice priority by one click on app.
On GitHub - https://github.com/firebbs/xrenice